# Incomplete data retrieved from web service

Tags: java, android, api, rest, web-services

I have an android application which retrieves data in JSON format from the REST web service of my site. I recently changed web hosts, and now the data that I retrieve is not complete. However when I invoke the web-service via the browser i can see the complete JSON file.

I send a GET request to the web service, I get the InputStream in a BufferedReader from an HttpURLConnection, and I put the response in a String.

```
        String response = null;


        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(Config.URL_API_ALL);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setConnectTimeout(10000);

            con.setReadTimeout(10000);

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            response = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

Is there something wrong with how I have implemented this function, or should I review my web service configuration? I appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: is your API response one-liner? as you are reading only one line from the socket. Please check once and use StringBuilder to concatenate response if possible.

Comment: thank you AlphaOne for your answer, yes my API is is programmed to send the response in one line

Comment: I did what you told me just to see but the result is the same : 

bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                for (String line; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
                reponse = total.toString();

Comment: That's weird. Have you checked the response in the mobile browser, or try to log each line from the response. If none is working. Try Retrofit library.

Answer (score 0):

finally the JSON file Imported from the web service is complete but contains errors, which causes bugs in the app, thanks for your help AlphaOne